# How many ways can six married couples be seated around a circular table if husbands and wives must be seated side by side?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

So if 6 married couples are seated around a circular table, how many ways can they do this if husband and wives must be seated side by side?

I figured if there are 6 couples there must be 12 individuals. From there we must find the number of 2 element subsets of these 12 individuals such that '12 choose 2' but since there are 6 couples we must divide by 6! is my thinking right?

Comment: Where did you get 8 couples?

Comment: @iiivooo I'm sorry I fixed it

Comment: A remark $12 \choose 2 $ is $66$ and $6!=720$.

Comment: I think you should take some time to understand the question before trying to answer it.  It would also be a good idea to write out a few examples of the seating.  For a start, the number of ways to split these $12$ people into married couples is not $C(12,2)$, it is of course just $1$, since they are already married couples.  That's ignoring the possibility of bigamy ;-)

Comment: Hint: A married couple together is like one individual except that they can be flipped (Aa or aA). So how many "flippable individuals" are there ?

Answer (score 2):

*Strong hint*

Seats in a circle are taken as unnumbered unless otherwise specified.

*n* people can be seated in $(n-1)$ ways in unnumbered seats in a circle.

With $6$ individuals it would be 5! ways, but these are $6$ "together" couples,

and each couple can be "flipped $[Aa\;\; or\;\; aA]$ so multiply by 2 for each couple.